# Apparent R bug--R associates wrong color to line on graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here's my code:

```
plotODs<- ggplot(data = yHeroin2, aes(x = Date, y = Heroin_Deaths)) +
    geom_point(aes(x = Date, y = Heroin_Deaths, color = 'blue')) 

plotODs <- plotODs +
    geom_point(data = yOpioids2, aes(x = Date, y = Opioid_Deaths, color = 'red')) +
    labs(x = 'years', y = 'total deaths')
```

But this is what it graphs:

[image: It graphs the line coded as red, blue, and the line coded as blue, red]

Does anybody know how to fix this? I tried reinstalling R but that didn't fix the problem.

Comment: When you specify `color = 'red'`, you are not actually saying that the colour should be red, but because it is inside `aes()`, you are saying that colour should be mapped to a string variable with value `'red'`. Here is an [explanation](https://ggplot2-book.org/getting-started.html#basic-use) of what an aesthetic mapping is in the ggplot2 book.

Comment: To make it clearer, try writing `color = 'banana'` and `color = 'apple'` instead of red and blue, and see what changes. Only the legend label will change but the colours will be the same, indicating that the colour comes from a **scale** specifically the default ggplot2 scale, not from the text string you are passing in.

Comment: Moving the color to outside of aes() worked. Thank you so much!